# In my Blazor server side app I want to change the text color in a razor page, depending on a variable value in the related razor.cs file. How to do?

Tags: c#, css, colors, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server side app I want to change the text color in a razor page, depending on a variable value in the related razor.cs file. How can I do that?

My Razor code:

```
 <table>
        @for (int f = 0; f < PLC_alarm_text.Count; f++)
        {
           <tr>
                <td class="alarm_color">@PLC_alarm_text[f]</td>                    
           </tr>
        }
 </table>
```

My Razor.cs code

```
 public string alarm_text_Type= "alarm";
 public List<string> PLC_alarm_text = new List<string>() { };


 public void function()
 {
   if(alarm_text_Type== "error")
   {
   PLC_alarm_text.Add("some error text")//for this case colour of "PLC_alarm_text" shall be red
   }
   if(alarm_text_Type== "message")
   {
   PLC_alarm_text.Add("some message text")//for this case colour of "PLC_alarm_text" shall be black
   }
 }
```

My css code

```
alarm_color {
color: black; // This should be conditional black or red
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method to determine the color that returns the css class and call it during the iteration.

```
<table>
    @for (int f = 0; f < PLC_alarm_text.Count; f++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="@GetTextColorClass(alarm_text_Type)">@PLC_alarm_text[f]</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

public string GetTextColorClass(string alarmType)
{
    if (alarmType == "error")
    {
        return "alarm_color_red";
    }
    else if (alarmType == "message")
    {
        return "alarm_color_black";
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty; // No special class
    }
}


.alarm_color_red {
    color: red;
}

.alarm_color_black {
    color: black;
}
```